# How to use Strings from strings.xml in another class

Tags: java, android, class

I'm currently writing an App, it gets JSON from a website, and then lists the contents in a listview. Now since the API itself only returns names like this: "`twisted_castle`" instead of "`Twisted Castle`", I created a new class to substitute the generic names to the right names, which I previously added to the strings.xml.

Now I can get Strings via `String test = getString(R.string.key)` in the MainActivity, but since I created a new class for the Substitute to happen, I somehow can't use `getString` somehow.

I already discovered that I'll need to get/use the context of MainActivity somehow, but really any solution I found didn't work, and also I'm a bit irritated on how the whole context thing works.

Anyone can help me with this and maybe has a good explanation on how contexts work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

Comment: Why do you create a new class for this? You could achieve this by just creating a method and pass the context as argument.

Comment: @Denny Because I want to split my code, so that I don't end up with one huge pile of code later..

Comment: @Denny So should I keep the method in the MainActivity? How do I decide then which things I should create an extra class for?

Comment: If it only requires an context, you could make a static method (in a different class) and pass the context from the mainactivity to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Context as:

```
mcontext.getString(R.string.something);
```

all you have to do is init context in the class some where like:

```
static Context mcontext;
public void setmContext(Context context){
  this.mcontext=context;
}
```

and call setmContext(this) from your activity or where ever you have context attribute

Comment: Thanks, this worked out, so I have to create a Context object in the class which needs it and then set it with the method which is also in that class, but I need to call it from the class which "has" the context? I'm trying to understand this, but I'm not that far with java yet.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android) will give you better understand about Context